# how to put multiple rows in a textblock?

Tags: textblock

I wan't to make it so if I Type a name into the textbox en press the button, that the name appers(I alredy have this).
But I wan't that if I type an other name, that the name comes under the other name. So if I type a name it will stay there(when the program is running). I'm programming phone apps in C#
Please someone help me..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

text can be added to a textblock element in VS with the Inlines property:

```
 textblock1.Inlines.Add(...);
```

you want to add a new line. For this usecase there is a Linebreak Class who inherits from the Inline Class:

```
 textBlock1.Inlines.Add(New Bold(New Run("John")))
 textBlock1.Inlines.Add(New LineBreak())
 textBlock1.Inlines.Add(New Bold(New Run("Anna")))
```

Comment: sry. corrected vb in VS. it's the same in vb.net or c#. doesn't matter

Comment: In this case you are doing something wrong. that's the way to do it. or if you want to deal with the text directly: textBlock1.Text = "first line" + Environment.NewLine + "second line" **EDIT** without telling us the errors we cannot help you! (please edit your question above. draw a line with three - characters and say Update: tried... but... with error...)